# A lower code coverage problem when trying to deploy

Tags: deployment, code-coverage

All my apex classes have more than 90% code coverage. But, when I am trying to deploy them, it is showing I have 59% code coverage. How to solve this issue.

I have run all test, & check all apex classes which I am trying to deploy. All those have >90% code coverage. [image: code coverage]
If code coverage = average of all individual coverage, my code coverage is supposed to be about 90% but it is showing 59% only.

Comment: Production environment and Sandbox environment can have some differences. For tests, the good pratices are to not set the `SeeAllData` to `true`. Also, don't put `try catch` in your tests. Maybe an error is raised but you can't see it on deployment.

Comment: Check this [issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5k3AAC).

Comment: Do you have test classes specifically covering the code you are deploying?  And do these test classes cover more than 75% of code you are trying to deploy?  If answer for both questions is yes, during deployment you have option to run specific test where you can select this new test class and you should be able to deploy your new code. And as good practice, it is always advisable to maintain org level code coverage above 75% and run all tests during deployment

Comment: " during deployment you have option to run specific test where you can select this new test class and you should be able to deploy your new code."

Comment: How can I run specific test?

Comment: Which deployment method you using?  Changeset or ant or eclipse?

Comment: If changeset, once it is uploaded to target org and on the screen where you validate your package, instead of choosing default, choose run specific tests and enter your new test class name in the text box. And validate your package. Note that your new test class should be part of your changeset..

Comment: I am creating Package to move all development from one org to another. My previous org is deactivated, therefore, need to backup all setup & metadata. 
I can't use changeset as I am moving outside of my org, 
I am not sure if Echipse is great way to development for this small development.Please suggest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52529/discussion-between-tanmoy-and-pmvsdt).

Comment: Take a look at this.. you can also use workbench for deployment and can run specific tests... `http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142465`